# Aggregated blur event using click and scroll from all other Backbone Views

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

**Use case:**

I have a `div#callout` that I want to `hide()` it if the user either clicks some other objects, scroll or doing nothing but timeout (120 seconds). But if the user clicks `#callout` or objects within it, it doesn't do the `hide()` action. Also if any children elements such as `input` got focus, the timeout is not effective (assuming people are typing).

**Idea:**

I am planning to create an aggregated event by extending `Backbone.Events` and any of those three events will trigger something like `"blur:callout"`

**Challenges:**

I guess I can do the scroll detection and timeout but how do I detect a click somewhere but NOT `#callout`? I don't want to add the trigger event for all of other views and subviews since there could be 100 of them and growing.

Comment: If you have a reference to the `div#callout` view, you could try triggering a message that that view would be listening for

Comment: Right, but if I have 100 other views or subviews, that would be alot of triggering for each of them on the `click` event

Comment: Hmm I am wondering tabindex is the answer here..lol http://www.barryvan.com.au/2009/01/onfocus-and-onblur-for-divs-in-fx/

Comment: You might be over-thinking this :)  See if my answer makes sense or maybe I'm missing context here

Answer (score 0):

So basically, the user has to click inside the `div#callout` within 120 seconds, otherwise it will hide.  You only have 2 cases then:

1. User clicks inside the callout before it hides i.e. within 120 seconds after the page loads
2. User ignores the `div#callout` and it is hidden automatically.

If the user does not interact with the `callout` then you have nothing to worry about.  The only case you have to worry about is whether a user clicks inside the `callout`.

So, unless you're going to have a large number of nested views inside `div#callout` you don't have a problem.

If you do have many nested views inside `div#callout`, you can attach a `reset hide` event to each child via some kind of inheritance or mixin.

Comment: Ah you made me think. I just modified the question. Basically if children elements onfocus, no timeout.

Comment: so you need to reset the timer whenever a user interacts with `callout` child elements? Basically, if a user interacts with anything inside the `callout` can you leave it __always__ visible?

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, then I would do something like this:

```
var Callout = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    "click": "clearTimeout" // clear timeout if clicked inside
  },

  render: function() {
    // render and then
    this.setTimeout();
    return this;
  },

  setTimeout: function() {
    var self = this;
    if (!this.timeout) {
      this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {self.hide();}, 120 * 1000);
    }
    return this;
  },

  clearTimeout: function(){
    if (this.timeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    }
    return this;
  },

  hide: function() {
    this.$el.hide();
    return this;
  }
)}
```

If you need to set timeout back then events hash would look like this (instead of blur events, [focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) event bubbles in jQuery)

```
events: {
  "focusout": "setTimeout",
  "focusin": "clearTimeout"
}
```

UPD: to ensure that `focusout` moves the focus out of `Callout` view, you'll need to check for event's [relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.relatedTarget) not to be inside view's `$el`.

Comment: Timeout is easy to handle. I just wonder about how to detect if user clicks other things outside.

Comment: Then I think you may need to extract this timeout functionality into object that has a constructor with Backbone.Events mixin. And then you pass it to all views to allow them communicate with each other. I think it is called mediator pattern.